# Composer is not picking up my release from Packagist

Tags: github, composer-php, packagist

I released a first version of my composer package on GitHub and submitted it on Packagist, however composer update doesn't work several hours ago.

```
"require": {
        "xolens/pglarautil": "1.0.0",
        "xolens/larautil-contract": "1.0.0",
        "xolens/larasetting-contract": "1.0.0"
},
```

I got the following error

Problem 1
    **- The requested package xolens/larasetting-contract 1.0.0 exists as xolens/larasetting-contract[9999999-dev] but these are rejected by your constraint.**

[GitHub URL](https://github.com/xolens/larasetting-contract)

[Packagist URL](https://packagist.org/packages/xolens/larasetting-contract)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click on "update" on the packagist or use webhooks on github to auto-update your packages as soon as you push code to them.